# Browsing an array without knowing if content exists

Tags: php, arrays

So, what à do is trying to display the 3 first element of an array. Always 3. But, there is not always at least 3 elements.

So, what I've done is using an if :

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) { ?>
  <?php if($post["Project"]["Post"][$i]){ ?>
    ...
  <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

But, I keep having "undefined offset" error when there is not 3 entries at least. Anyone with a solution ?

Comment: The force is strong with this one... 2 minute 5 answers!

Comment: btw, what you want to do when 3 element is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
   if(isset($post["Project"]["Post"][$i])){ ?>
   ...
<?php }} ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (array_slice($array, 0, 3) as $item) {
    echo $item;
    ...
}
```

or:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    ...

    if ($i++ >= 3) {
        break;
    }
}
```

`foreach` is always preferable to iterate arrays, precisely because you cannot access anything that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isset()` to check whether the key exists.

```
<?php if(isset($post["Project"]["Post"][$i])){ ?>
```

Or you could use:

```
$posts = $post["Project"]["Post"];
foreach ($posts as $i => $post) {
   //...
   if ($i === 2) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to `if (isset($post ...`

Alternatively:

```
foreach (array_slice($post["Project"]["Post"], 0, 3)) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) { 
  if( isset($post["Project"]["Post"][$i] )){ 
  ...
 } 
}   ?>
```

you do not need `<?php...?>` tags for every line.

Comment: Yep, I shouldn't have putted them, it's because there is some HTML between in my file.

Answer (score 0):

try ifset.

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) { ?>
  <?php if(isset($post["Project"]["Post"][$i])){ ?>
    ...
  <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Or, do a count first could be a way too.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate before, which condition is met first (the actual size of the array or the max number - in your case 3) and then just traverse those elements:

```
$min = min( 3, count( $post["Project"]["Post"] ) );
for ($i = 0; $i < $min; $i++) {
 if($post["Project"]["Post"][$i]){
    ...
 }
}
```

Comment: I would do it like `for ($i = 0, $min = min(3, count($post["Project"]["Post"])); $i < $min; $i++) { … }` to not invoke another variable in the scope above.

Comment: @insertusernamehere fair point. i just separated it for readability above.

Comment: @inserusernamehere: In PHP it's considered a bad practice to include the count in the exit condition (inside the for). Over the span of 3 repetitions it doesn't hava a big impact, but as you add elements, your loop will get slower and slower (http://www.phpbench.com/ see counting loops)

Comment: @JFDion I can't find an example on the link, that shows, that this is slower. The comparative value is calculated once before the loop starts running, so there should not be a difference. Or is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: @insertusernamehere there is two sections named counting loops and counting inside the exit condition of a for loop is about 44000% less efficient than using a pre-calculated value

Comment: @JFDion I can only find the first section. But there is a difference between `for ($i = 0; $i < count($i); ++$i) {}` and `for ($i = 0, $j = count($i); $i < $j; ++$i) {}`, because the latter pre-calculates the value and it's the one I used in my first comment.